# Evaluating the Euler-Lagrange equation for a vector valued function

Tags: differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, variational-analysis

I am trying to solve a problem currently and I have the setup needed that lets me find the Euler-Lagrange equation for a vector valued problem.

The Lagrangian for the equation relates to the energy of a surface that is parameterized in terms of variables e1 and e2 (where normally people may use variables u and v instead). The vector x is the general position vector describing the surface and the subsequent subscripts denote the derivatives of position vector in those parametrized coordinates.

$$ \mathcal L = \iint F(e_1,e_2,\vec x_1(e_1,e_2),\vec x_2(e_1,e_2),\vec x_{12}(e_1,e_2)) $$

The corresponding Euler-Lagrange equation we arrive at is.

$$ -\frac{\partial}{\partial  e_1}(\frac{\partial F}{\partial \vec x_1}) - \frac{\partial}{\partial  e_2}(\frac{\partial F}{\partial \vec x_2}) + \frac{\partial}{\partial  e_1 \partial  e_2}(\frac{\partial F}{\partial \vec x_{12}}) $$

With boundary conditions that I am not including. My question is, what is the proper approach to taking the derivative of a function F with respect to a vector? There is some uncertainty on my part on what exactly the notation is supposed to mean when a vector is involved in the derivative operator.

I will give a specific example of a function. How would I evaluate this?

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec x_1}(\langle \vec x_1,\vec x_2 \rangle)$$

I guess more specifically, I am not even sure of how to go about evaluating the first part of this which would be

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec x_1}(\vec x_1)$$

Am I just supposed to interpret this as taking the covariant derivative?

Comment: No, it's not a covariant derivative. Derivatives at a point are by definition linear transformations from the domain vector space to the target vector space. Google the term "Frechet derivative". For your first example, it is the linear transformation $\langle \cdot, \vec{x}_2\rangle$, and for the second, it is the identity linear transformation. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3260251/568204) is just one of many answers where I write the definitions more carefully (if you want more examples, look through other answers I've written, or others have written)..

Comment: My previous comment links to an answer I wrote on MSE explaining the definitions/theory. [Here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/575825/203278) is a link to an answer I wrote on Physics SE where I show how one can use all this jargon to carry out standard calculations which come up in physics. So maybe this example computation will help you digest the definitions.